# Is there any software for Mac OSX that manages launching of groups of apps?

Tags: macos, shortcuts

I would like to be able to click a shortcut and launch a set of programs / open a number of different files in their respective programs. Is there any software that does this?

For example, when I am working on a specific project, I need to launch several different programs, and load files into these programs, then arrange these windows on my screen. It would be a huge time saver if this could be done at the click of the button.

It would be fairly straightforward to write a script that handles the file / program opening, but if a gui based program exists to manage these types of sessions I would prefer that.

Comment: Sidenote; really wish this would have been built into tiles in Win8 and Win10 too :(

Comment: @panhandel Similarly to the way I showed for OS X, you can do the exact same thing with [Windows](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/launch-multiple-programs-single-shortcut-using-batch-file/).

Answer (score 1):

The best software is the software built into your Mac. I know you said you would *prefer* a GUI based program (and this isn't the place for software recommendations, really) but this is honestly so simple it's ridiculous.

1. Open your `Script Editor` (Go to Finder --> Applications --> Utilities Folder)

[image]

2. Once open, click "File --> New" from the top
3. Paste the following into your script:

```
tell application "Calculator" to activate
tell application "Calendar" to activate
tell application "Dictionary" to activate
```

4. Pressing the run icon will test it out. (And of course, edit the name of the applications to suit what you're doing.)

[image]

5. Finally go to File --> Export, then change the fie format to `Application`

[image]

6. You're done! Simply run your App which will open multiple apps at once.

**Side Note:**

I just realized you wanted to be able to **open files too**. This is easy with [AppleScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10132641/3893016):

```
tell application "Finder" to open POSIX file "/Users/xxx/my/file/to/open.xyz"
```

This will open the file using the default program. Hope this covers all bases.