# Using a hotkey to toggle a USB input device

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I'm looking for a way to enable and disable an Xbox 360 controller which is connected via USB using a custom hotkey.

Comment: If it was me, I would make a batch script to execute [this](http://ccm.net/faq/1886-enable-disable-a-device-from-the-command-line) in a toggle fashion, then setup an AHK program to run the script on hotkey press. This isn't an "easy task" to say the least.

Comment: With having close to no experience with batch files, I'm thinking that this might be feasible for me to delve into. However, is there any risk in trying to tinker with this?

Comment: I don't really see any major risks trying. The [last](http://superuser.com/a/986767/498587) [time](http://superuser.com/a/987401/498587) I setup a detailed guide from scratch for someone on how to do something like this it got little response so I'm hesitant to do it again :P

Comment: Oh man. Something like that would be awesome though. Especially because the link to Devcon.exe doesn't exist anymore, and now I'm trying to find it elsewhere on microsofts website.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a Batch file, and [DEVCON](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544707(v=vs.85).aspx) (program for working with USB).

1. [Download DEVCON](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=536682)
2. Enter the following code in a batch file

```
 @echo off
SET usbDeviceName = " "
IF counter = 1 (
     start /w devcon disable %usbDeviceName%
     SET counter = 0
) ELSE (
     start /w devcon enable %usbDeviceName%
     SET counter = 1
)
```